# template inheritance error in c++

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, header-files

I have two header files A.h(include a pure virtual function) and B.h.

A.h :

```
#ifndef __A_H__
#define __A_H__

#include "B.h"
template <class T>
class A
{
   virtual B<T> f()=0;
};

#endif
```

B.h :

```
#ifndef __B_H__
#define __B_H__

#include "A.h"
template <class T>
class B : public A <T> 
{
  B<T> f(){}
};

#endif
```

but when I compile it gives me error like that  
**In file included from B.h:4, 

                 from Test.cpp:1: 

A.h:10: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘B’ with no type 

A.h:10: error: ‘B’ declared as a ‘virtual’ field 

A.h:10: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘<’ token**

```
#include "B.h"

int main() {
 return 0;
}
```

how can I solve this ?
thanks

Comment: Can you explain *why* an abstract base class would need to declare a virtual function that returns an instance of a derived class?  I know that your code is a minimal example, but I don't see why you'd need this.  Seems like you would want to approach it differently.

Comment: same logic with the links below

Comment: An unrelated note: Names with double underscores, such as `__A_H__`, are reserved for the implementation (i.e. the compiler and standard library). Therefore it's a good idea to adopt another convention.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way is with forward declare :

```
#ifndef __A_H__
#define __A_H__

template< typename > class B;

template <class T>
class A
{
   virtual B<T>* f()=0;
};

#endif
```

You have a problem with [circular dependency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency#Problems_of_circular_dependencies) which can be solved only [using forward declare](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/misc-technical-issues.html#faq-39.11).